# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in socket.io

Tags: javascript, express, websocket, socket.io

I have gone through many other questions on the same topic but couldn't found the useful answer, so I have to ask this again.

I am working on a stock ticker POC which receives the sample stocks data from this server url: **ws://stocks.mnet.website**. But I am getting this error
https://stocks.mnet.website/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LwRYHVy net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

client side:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

var socket = io('https://stocks.mnet.website');
socket.on('connect', function() {
          socket.on('ticker', function(data) {
          console.log(data);
});
});
```

Server Side:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = 8080;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("New connection made");
});

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("Listening on port " + port);
});
```

If I use my http://localhost:8080 or any other WebSocket url for eg https://websocket.btcchina.com/ then I can successfully fetch the data.
Is there anything wrong with my socket url mentioned in code.

Comment: The given stocks url is not accessible for me.

Comment: Is it means that there is something wrong with the Url which is given to me?

Comment: I also tested the url and chrome says this: This site can’t be reached

Comment: Is `https://stocks.mnet.website` the name of your host? Or some random website?

Comment: The owner of the url told me it is a valid url and I should be getting the data.